# tagged and min max creation gives wrong total

Tags: bug, status-completed

I am trying to get the total number of question with a specific tag AND created within a specific date span.

For example, the number of questions tagged as 'java' created between 16 and 17 Jan 2012:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions?order=asc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&filter=total&min=1326668400&max=1326754800&tagged=java

But this returns a very large number, much larger that the number of questions created in the same date span, for example:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions?order=asc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&filter=total&min=1326668400&max=1326754800

It looks like that when tagged is present, min and max do not work properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

Really fun set of bugs there actually.

In the API we delegate most tag operations to a couple (conceptually) external services, there was a dodge bit of logic in building the request w.r.t. min/max creation dates.

However, fixing that revealed another more pervasive bug around date precision.  Most of the API, and the backing databases, store dates out to about a thousandth of a second; a number of service (and the APIs external representation) work at a single second precision.  This mismatch caused a number of `>=` and `<=` comparisons to really mess up counts and result sets.